# Vercel deployment Preview URL notification in bitbucket PR comments

Tags: bitbucket, comments, vercel

Is there any configuration to be set in bitbucket or Vercel to auto update Preview URL after every vercel deployment in bitbucket PR comments. (without using Rest API or webhook)??

Vercel is connected with bitbucket

Comment: With bitbucket integration, is there any configuration setting to make Vercel bot automatically  posts Preview Deployments in the bitbucket pull request